# Having problems with CALayer

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

So I have a class that returns a CALayer that has an array of CALayers added as sublayers, but the problem is that it doesn't seem to be rendering any of them. I think I may just be missing something about how CALayers work as I'm not very familiar yet. Could someone please take a look at my code to see what I am doing wrong?

```
- (CALayer*)drawMap {
    CALayer* theLayer = [CALayer layer];
    for (int y = 0; y < [self.height intValue]; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < [self.width intValue]; x++) {
            CALayer* tileLayer = [CALayer layer];
            tileLayer.bounds = CGRectMake((x * [self.tileWidth intValue]), (y * [self.tileHeight intValue]), [self.tileWidth intValue], [self.tileHeight intValue]);
            [tileLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:(CGFloat)x saturation:(CGFloat)y brightness:255 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
            [theLayer addSublayer:tileLayer];
        }
    }
    [theLayer setBounds:CGRectMake([self.width intValue] * [self.tileWidth intValue], [self.height intValue] * [self.tileHeight intValue], 10, 10)];
    return theLayer;       
}
```

This is the code that initializes and draws the map.

```
Map* myMap = [[Map alloc] initFromFile];
[myMap setWidth:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
[myMap setHeight:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]]; 

[self.view.layer insertSublayer:[myMap drawMap] above:self.view.layer];
```

I can provide the headers if needed, but I don't think the problem is there and I don't want a huge post.

Comment: Obvious question: do tileWidth and tileHeight have reasonable values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the bounds you're setting to your parent layer:

```
[theLayer setBounds:
                CGRectMake(
                           [self.width intValue] * [self.tileWidth intValue], 
                           [self.height intValue] * [self.tileHeight intValue], 
                           10, 10)];
```

That would appear to set the bounds so that it starts just exactly past all the sublayers you've just added and extends for 10 points in both directions. I think the following would be more appropriate:

```
[theLayer setBounds:
                CGRectMake(
                           0, 
                           0, 
                           [self.width intValue] * [self.tileWidth intValue], 
                           [self.height intValue] * [self.tileHeight intValue])];
```

The following also looks fishy:

```
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:[myMap drawMap] above:self.view.layer];
```

`[myMap drawMap]` will become a sublayer of `self.view.layer`. `self.view.layer` is not one of its own subviews so it won't know what to do with that `above:` instruction. You probably want just `addSublayer:`.

Finally, this:

```
tileLayer.bounds = CGRectMake((x * [self.tileWidth intValue]), (y * [self.tileHeight intValue]), [self.tileWidth intValue], [self.tileHeight intValue]);
```

gives every single one of your sublayers exactly the same `frame`. Much like `UIView`s, the `bounds` are the source area for information and the frame is where that information will be put within the super layer. I think probably you want to set `frame`.

Finally, `UIColor +colorWithHue:...` clamps hue and saturation to the range [0, 1] so you probably want `(CGFloat)x / [self.width floatValue]` and the equivalent for saturation to ensure all your tiles come out in different colours.

EDIT: so, tying all that together, I modified your code slightly so that I didn't have to write the full encompassing class and added it to the Xcode view-based project template as follows:

```
#define kTileWidth  3
#define kTileHeight 3
#define kWidth 100
#define kHeight 100

- (CALayer*)drawMap {
    CALayer* theLayer = [CALayer layer];
    for (int y = 0; y < kHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < kWidth; x++)
        {
            CALayer* tileLayer = [CALayer layer];
            tileLayer.frame = CGRectMake((x * kTileWidth), (y * kTileHeight), kTileWidth, kTileHeight);
            [tileLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:(CGFloat)x/kWidth saturation:(CGFloat)y/kHeight brightness:255 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
            [theLayer addSublayer:tileLayer];
        }
    }
    [theLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth * kTileWidth, kHeight * kTileHeight)];
    return theLayer;       
}

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:[self drawMap]];
}
```

That gives the hue/saturation plane familiar from many an art package.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I'm just learning all of this core animation stuff, so I assumed that was the mistake, but it looks like all of my mistakes were basic stuff.

Comment: I wasn't worried so much about getting the colors right, I just wanted to color the tiles so that I could see them. I'm trying to make a 2D tiled game engine using Core Animation.